# Prolog, not sure as to why it is returning no

Tags: prolog

In this example Sophia is the mother of George.

When I type in  the code: `motherOf(sophia,george).` prolog returns yes.

However if I type: `motherOf(X,george).` it returns `X=sophia ?`  I type y but it returns no.

What is the reason for it returning no when it should be yes.

Comment: Another example is if I do `motherOf(sophia,Y).` it returns `Y = george` yes.

Comment: What prolog implementation are you using?

Comment: @aBathologist gprolog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No." because there aren't any other solutions. If sophia has more than one child, you'll be given both solutions when querying for "motherOf(sophia, Y)." before computer says "No."
Try it with an additional "motherOf(sophia, homer)." clause in the DB.

Comment: Thanks, just making sure I didn't make a mistake. I even noticed if I just press return instead it will return a yes.

Comment: @BobDunakey that's because when you press return you are telling Prolog not to search for any more solutions. So there isn't a failure to find another (which is why entering `;` yields a "no" since it searches for another and fails). When you entered `motherOf(sophia,george).` it only has one choice since there are no uninstantiated variables, so it returns "yes" if what you typed is true or it would return "no" if it didn't find it (it was false).